# Symfony $this->>createFormBuilder throws notice from controller

Tags: symfony

I am doing a small project in Symfony to gain some experience with this framework. At the moment I am just following tutorials while making my own tool which is a GUI to make my resume.

In my controller I am calling `$this->createFormBuilder($cvBase)` which is throwing an "Undefined property" notice which I think is strange because I am calling a method.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

```
<?php
// My php code
namespace NuiCart\CvToolBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use NuiCart\CvToolBundle\Entity\CvBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller{

public function formAction(Request $request){
    $cvBase = new CvBase();    
    $form   = new $this->createFormBuilder($cvBase);
```

The notice:

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   NuiCart\CvToolBundle\Controller\DefaultController::$createFormBuilder
>   in
>   /var/www/devel/cv/public_html/src/NuiCart/CvToolBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
>
> line 19 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createFormBuilder()` [already returns a newly created `FormBuilder` object](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_createFormBuilder) and you therefore don't need to create a new Object. By attempting to use `new`, it is trying to create a new `DefaultController` and access a function that is private to the internals of the Controller (or something like that - don't sue me for correctness on this one as it is just an attempt to explain *why* using `new $this` is wrong.)

Your solution is to remove the `new` in `$this->createFormBuilder()`:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($cvBase);
```

Comment: Pff, i have been staring at this for at least an hour. Haha, thanks a lot!

Comment: @AntonBoutkam No problem! If you feel that an answer has helped you and solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the grey "checkmark" button located immediately below the up/down vote buttons!